# Generic class inheritance in Swift

Tags: ios, generics, inheritance, swift

I have the following class:

```
class BaseCache<T: Equatable>: NSObject {

    var allEntities = [T]()

    // MARK: - Append

    func appendEntities(newEntities: [T]) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Now I want to subclass it, but I get annoying error, that my type "does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'":
[image]

It seems generics in Swift are real pain-in-the-ass.

Comment: It might be easier just to add the the protocol at the class definition. `class Aftership : Equatable { }`

Comment: That's impossible, because Aftership SDK is written on Objective C

Comment: Maybe put the == func inside the extension so it is actually conforming to the protocol.

Comment: == func must be global, so it must be outside of extension definition. Actually, `AftershipTracking` conforms to `Equatable` protocol, otherwise I'd get a compiler warning on extension row.

Comment: Looks like you have to skip generics altogether. I really hate some of the limitations of swift generics.

Comment: Yeah, it would be better if guys from Apple didn't add generics to the first version of the language.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your class definition of `TrackingCache` is wrong. It repeats the generic parameter:

```
class TrackingCache<AftershipTracking>: BaseCache<AftershipTracking> { }
```

It should be left out:

```
class TrackingCache: BaseCache<AftershipTracking> { }
```

This triggers the underlying swift error `Classes derived from generic classes must also be generic`. You can work around this issue by specifying a type parameter that is required to be or inherit from AftershipTracking:

```
class TrackingCache<T: AftershipTracking>: BaseCache<AftershipTracking> { }
```

Full example:

```
class BaseCache<T: Equatable>: NSObject {
  var items: [T] = []

  func appendItems( items: [T]) {
    self.items += items
    didAppendItems()
  }

  func didAppendItems() {} // for overriding
}

class AftershipTracking: NSObject {
  var identifier: Int
  init( identifier: Int) {
    self.identifier = identifier
    super.init()
  }
}

extension AftershipTracking: Equatable { }

func ==( lhs: AftershipTracking, rhs: AftershipTracking) -> Bool {
  return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
}

class TrackingCache<T: AftershipTracking>: BaseCache<AftershipTracking> {
  override func didAppendItems() {
    // do something
  }
}

let a = TrackingCache<AftershipTracking>()
let b = TrackingCache<AftershipTracking>()

a.appendItems( [AftershipTracking( identifier: 1)])
b.appendItems( [AftershipTracking( identifier: 1)])

let result = a.items == b.items // true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried that already and it didn't work. If I define my class as `class TrackingCache<T: AftershipTracking>: BaseCache<AftershipTracking>`, I get an error "Method does not override any method from it's superclass" on each `override func` row.

Comment: Yes, but that's another issue. Your BaseCache class derives from something else than NSObject right? As soon as you derive a generic class from an Objective-C class, the derived swift class can't see the super-methods anymore. You can work around this by introducing an intermediate non-generic subclass in swift. But this is really a separate issue. My answer is the correct solution to your question.

Comment: BaseCache derives directly from NSObject, as stated above. Even if I remove NSObject, that doesn't change anything

Comment: If a method that you try to override has a generic type in its parameter list it will be a different method: `appendItems( items: [Equatable])` is different from `appendItems( items: [AftershipTracking])`. You can still call the supermethod though. I'll update the example.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the previous issue, but gives another one. When I try to call `appendEntities` method, I get an error: `Ambiguous use of 'appendEntities'`. I can't understand why compiler thinks that `AfterTracking` and `T` are a different types - that's the problem

Comment: Yes, you're right, doesn't really make sense that they are different methods. I updated the example with another workaround.

Answer (score 8):

this should work: < swift 4 >

```
class TrackingCache<T: AftershipTracking>: BaseCache<T>
```

Another example:

```
protocol P {

}

class C: P {

}

class CS: C {

}

class L<T:P> {
    let c: T

    init(_ c: T) {
        self.c = c
    }
}

class LS<T:CS>:L<T> {

}

let i = LS(CS())

i.c
```

`c` is `CS` now.